# Rails Simple_Form: How to show long name of the country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, format, simple-form, country

I use `simple_form` gem to select country:

```
= simple_form_for @shop, :url => { :action => "create" }, :html => {:id => 'new_shop' } do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :address, :html => {:multipart => true} do |o|
    = o.input :country, :label => "Country"
```

But the name of the country is being saved in short format in the database (like `RU`, `FR`, `AU`, and so on).

I wonder, how can I show the full, long name of the country in the views? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) gem?

Comment: Have long format contry in database?

Comment: @Зелёный, no , it's in short format in the DB.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem as you

Answer (score 0):

Actually is a good idea saving the country code in the database (not the long name) because I18n. Having the code you can get later the name as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Assuming country_select is used with User attribute `country_code`
  # This will attempt to translate the country name and use the default
  # (usually English) name if no translation is available
  def country_name
    country = ISO3166::Country[country_code]
    country.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || country.name
  end
end
```

Check: [country_select: Getting the Country Name from the countries gem](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select#getting-the-country-name-from-the-countries-gem)

Answer (score 0):

This worked really nicely for me (I had occasional `nil`s and `""`).

In `application_helper.rb`:

```rb
def country_name(country_code)
  unless country_code.nil? || country_code == ""
    country = ISO3166::Country[country_code]
    country.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || country.common_name || country.iso_short_name
  end
end
```

In the view

```
<%= country_name(@user.country_code) %>
```

It's based on the [country_select](https://github.com/countries/country_select#getting-the-country-name-from-the-countries-gem) docs.

#### Example usage

```rb
arr = ["AU", "US", nil, ""]
arr.map{ |country_code| country_name(country_code) }
# => ["Australia", "United States", nil, nil]
```